# Instagram camera page

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have implemented the camera roll when I click the middle button just like in instagram using the function ShouldSelectViewController. And if I hit cancel, it goes back to the tab before. The problem I m having now is that, I would like to show another view controller with the selected image. Is there any function that can me to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `UIImagePickerController`, there is a delegate method you can implement to handle what happens after a picture is selected.

```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
      //do something with the image 
    }
  }
```

You can `segue` to another view controller in this method via the regular patterns. For example, let's say you decide to put the image in another view controller called `AnotherViewController`.

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
  let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("anotherViewController") as! AnotherViewController
  vc.imageToDisplay = image
  presentViewControllerAnimated(vc, animated: true)
}
```